# Laravel Session Drivers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Can anybody explain session drivers to me? A search on "laravel session drivers" revealed nothing about the different types. I ask because the following tutorial suggested using an array driver for a REST API, but I don't know why. Tutorial: https://speakerdeck.com/akuzemchak/simple-api-development-with-laravel?slide=62

Here's the relevant section from app/config/session.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "native", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'native',
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's quite easy. Driver defines where session data will be stored.

- `native` - session will be handled by internal PHP rutines
- `cookie` - session will be stored in cookies
- `database` - session will be stored in database (by default in table `sessions`)
- `memcached`/`redis` - use one of this daemons as a session storage
- `array` - session will be stored in a plain array (it's handled by [MockArraySessionStorage](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/MockArraySessionStorage.php))

`array` driver means that session is only per request (stored during PHP runtime), and after that it disappears :)

Comment: Thank you! It's disappointing that this isn't anywhere in the Laravel docs.

Comment: how can I use redis/memcached driver in laravel? I know there is a driver, How can I use that driver?

Comment: Just change driver in config file (`app/config/session.php`)?

Comment: It's in the documentation at the bottom of the page.

http://laravel.com/docs/session#session-drivers

Comment: laravel 5+ has dropped `native`

Comment: laravel 5+ has 'file' instead of 'native'.

Comment: so the old `natvie`option was basically running `session_start()` and `session()->put('name' ,'x')`was identical to `$_SESSION['name']=x`?